# Difference between two end of line signs

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, search, replace

Both `$` and `\n` represents the end of a line. To remove an empty line we can use either `:g/^$/d` or `:%s/^\n//g`

My questions are:

What's the difference between these two signs?

It seems the first command *removes* a line while the latter one *replaces* a line by nothing. Hence the first one should be more efficient than the second one. Is my analysis correct?

What about the comparison between `:g/^$/d` and `:g/^\n/d`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it briefly, `$` (and `^`) are null-size, empty markers that, when replaced, actually remove nothing (so you basically append to the line), while `\n` stands for the character (or characters) separating 2 lines: if  you replace `\n`, you will also join those lines.

That's why if you replace your substitute example with `%s/^$//g`, nothing happens.

The `:g/^$/d` works because the pattern is only used to *find* the line, and `d` (delete) is the one actually removing the line, EOL included (since it is an Ex command).